# Base table missing on Database Restore

Tags: 7, installation, backups

**Problem**

I just tried to revert to a recent backup and got a very strange error.

- Wiped database.
- Deleted drupal base folder.
- Copied in new Drupal folder (from backup).
- Ran install.php

Re-installing was successful (except for the failure to send an email), but on loading the site I got the following error:

`PDOException: SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1146 Table 'mysite2.languages' doesn't exist: SELECT * FROM {languages} ORDER BY weight ASC, name ASC; Array ( ) in language_list() (line 2727 of /srv/www/mysite2/public/includes/bootstrap.inc).`

Any idea what could've caused this?

**My Thoughts**

I've not restored the the database yet so I don't quite understand what could cause this? None of the modules that I have in my build should begin enabled after a basic install.

But it does seem as if some part of my folders or modules are interfering with a basic drupal install, calling something which doesn't exist yet and blocking me. Even though they shouldn't be enabled.

Comment: Are you using redis/memcache?

Comment: @Clive. You're too smart Clive now I feel like an idiot. Thanks once again!

Comment: You don't have to run install when restoring a site. All you should need is to restore the site and configuration files, and restore your database snapshot.

Comment: @keithm Hmm that's interesting. Everytime I've tried to restore using BaM on an existing database I've found it throws some sort of row already exists error. I have to wipe the database, re-install drupal, re-enable BaM and restore then. Presumably I'm missing something?

Comment: @DominicWoodman If you can, try to restore using external tools, like command line MySQL clients. Running restored site (to get BaM) on unrestored DB causes errors like that. Also, never backup data from `{cache}` and `{cache_%}` tables.

Comment: @Molot Cheers, I'll try and learn to do it another way. I gravitated to BaM in the beginning because it was the simplest. I'll see if I can switch to MySQL command line now.

Comment: @DominicWoodman BaM is good for *making* backups. And it produces SQL dumps compatible with other MySQL clients. It just lacks a bit when it comes to restore... But it's not it's fault per se, it's bound to have problems like this when used with http. Anyway, it's not called "Backup and Migrate and Restore" ;) I only use it to fast restore nonessential tables during module development. For this task, it's great. If by great you mean "works and you only need few clicks", that is.

Comment: At a Unix command line, it's very simple. First use mysql: drop database sample_db; create database sample_db default character set utf8 collate utf8_unicode_ci. Then from the command line execute: mysql < sample_db.sql

Comment: Cheers guys. I'm going to have to go and practice this. Thank you very much for the help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solved by Clive. I had memcached running. It had stored chunks of the code from my original site and tried to run them on the new version. Clearing or restarting memcached solved the problem.

Edit:

An overly simplified explanation of memcached for anyone who's unsure what I'm talking about.

Memcached caches chunks of code. It's best illustrated by a contrast. Varnish caches a static picture of a page and sends that to people when it's requested. It will bypass PHP processing completely.

Memcached won't stop the processing for the page happening each time, but it will remember chunks of the processing and deliver the result straight from the cache.

When I wiped my server and reverted to a backup I forgot to restart memcached. This means that memcached had still remembered chunks of my PHP code. This code didn't fit in with the older revert of my website so I got a horrible error. Restarting memcached or flushing the memcached cache will solve this.